# Running spell check on Test Cases and Test Scripts in RQM

Tags: automated-tests, spell-checking, ibm-jazz

I can't seem to find a good way to spell check test cases and test scripts using Rational Quality Manager.  I can do dumb things like bring up the Assisted Data Entry/Verification feature, enter some text, have it auto-magically spell checked, then select/copy/paste the text into the step Description/Expected Results but yuk.

What techniques are other people using?  I have fat fingers so a spell checker would come in handy.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Rational Help file for the Jazz suite:

You can edit and check the spelling in all rich-text artifacts if your browser supports spell checking. Misspelled words are marked with a red wavy underline.

Tip: To spell check rich-text artifacts using Internet Explorer, you must install a spell check plug-in. Spell checkers for Internet Explorer include ieSpell (for V7) and Google Toolbar (for V8).

Comment: Eric, Thank you.  Other rich text fields are spell checked (I am using IE9).  I don't think that the steps and expected results are RTF.  Since I posted, I found this reference:  http://reviews.cnet.com/search-results/ibm-rational-quality-manager/1707-5_7-33571501.html.

Comment: "It's disappointing for RQM. It is so user unfriendly.
by vd1688 - November 14, 2011
Pros: It can allow user to enter something.

Cons: 1. Why not to let user to export or copy the test script out?
2. Why not to allow user to import or copy the test script into RQM from Excel?
3. Why not to allow user do a spell check in test script?
4. Why not to support some basic features in MS Word an"